# Ansible parameters for module 'copy'/'template' is not work

Tags: ansible

I don't know how to pass both parameters for the module 'copy'.

But as the documentation said, you just simply use a space to separate the parameters.

What has been missed?

(It's the same error when I use the module 'template'. And the connection and auth is good)

```
> ansible all -m ping                                
test-ansible-slave1 | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false, 
    "ping": "pong"
}
test-ansible-slave2 | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false, 
    "ping": "pong"
}

> ansible all -m copy -a 'src=/home/root/httpd.conf desc=/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf'
test-ansible-slave1 | FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "dest is required"
}
test-ansible-slave2 | FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "dest is required"
}

> ansible all -m template -a 'desc=/var/log/test.log src=/home/root/httpd.conf'
test-ansible-slave1 | FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "src and dest are required"
}
test-ansible-slave2 | FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "src and dest are required"
}
```

Comment: Spelling error: `desc` should be `dest`.

Comment: OMG! thank u. It was embarrassing.

Comment: Happens to the best of us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

typo!!! actually work in both copy and template.

```
> ansible all -m template -a 'dest=/var/log/test.log src=/home/root/httpd.conf'
test-ansible-slave2 | CHANGED => {
    "changed": true, 
    "checksum": "3a54cdfa12e333664b03b1eabedd809c22732241", 
    "dest": "/var/log/test.log", 
    "gid": 0, 
    "group": "root", 
    "md5sum": "f5a0d8a8b78c3bc29bc50bd82de09f48", 
    "mode": "0644", 
    "owner": "root", 
    "size": 5797, 
    "src": "/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1582685105.18-135902842538994/source", 
    "state": "file", 
    "uid": 0
}
test-ansible-slave1 | CHANGED => {
    "changed": true, 
    "checksum": "3a54cdfa12e333664b03b1eabedd809c22732241", 
    "dest": "/var/log/test.log", 
    "gid": 0, 
    "group": "root", 
    "md5sum": "f5a0d8a8b78c3bc29bc50bd82de09f48", 
    "mode": "0644", 
    "owner": "root", 
    "size": 5797, 
    "src": "/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1582685105.18-75242459625521/source", 
    "state": "file", 
    "uid": 0
}

> ansible all -m copy -a 'dest=/var/log/test.log src=/home/root/httpd.conf'
test-ansible-slave2 | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false, 
    "checksum": "3a54cdfa12e333664b03b1eabedd809c22732241", 
    "dest": "/var/log/test.log", 
    "gid": 0, 
    "group": "root", 
    "mode": "0644", 
    "owner": "root", 
    "path": "/var/log/test.log", 
    "size": 5797, 
    "state": "file", 
    "uid": 0
}
test-ansible-slave1 | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false, 
    "checksum": "3a54cdfa12e333664b03b1eabedd809c22732241", 
    "dest": "/var/log/test.log", 
    "gid": 0, 
    "group": "root", 
    "mode": "0644", 
    "owner": "root", 
    "path": "/var/log/test.log", 
    "size": 5797, 
    "state": "file", 
    "uid": 0
}
```